# simple form value methods in a grouped select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to figure out how I can assign the value methods to a group select method when using simple_form.

Currently it looks like this:

```
  <%= f.input :frequency, collection: options_for_question_frequencies, as: :grouped_select,
      group_method: :first, group_label_method: :last, value_method: :downcase %>
```

and my helper method looks like this:

```
  def options_for_question_frequencies
    {
      ['weekly'] => 'weekly',
      ['starting this week', 'starting next week'] => 'biweekly',
      ['First week of month', 'last week of month'] => 'monthly',
      ['start of quarter', 'end of quarter'] => 'quarterly'
    }
  end
```

now I'm trying to figure out how I can add my value methods into the helper method. I obviously don't want the value method to be the downcase of the label method, it's just a filler. How can I make it so that I can have a unique value method to each?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to rearrange the parts of your hash. Using :first and :last is not really the way to go in this case. I do not how it works exactly, but you can probably do it like this:

```
 def options_for_question_frequencies
    [
      ['weekly', [[1,'weekly']]],
      ['biweekly', [[2, 'starting this week'],[3,'starting next week']]],
    ]
  end
```

And call it like this:

```
f.select :frequency, grouped_options_for_select(options_for_question_frequencies)
```

Have a look at: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select

Comment: I'm using simple form, not the form options helper - which changes things.